# ¿Cómo hacer un objeto de tipo arraylist en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, arraylist

Tengo una duda con respecto al ArrayList de vb.net que he estado buscando por internet pero no he encontrado una referencia que me ayude.

Como el título de la pregunta dice, estoy intentando hacer una ArrayList de tipo objeto.

Tengo una clase llamada Simbolo

```
Public Class Simbolo
Private numero As Integer
Private componente As String
Private lex As String
Private linea As Integer
Private columna As Integer


Public Sub New(ByVal numero As Integer, ByVal componente As String, ByVal lex As String, ByVal linea As Integer, ByVal columna As Integer)

    Me.numero = numero
    Me.componente = componente
    Me.lex = lex
    Me.linea = linea
    Me.columna = columna

End Sub
```

En otra clase quiero crear y arrayList con el constructor de Simbolo.
Me servirá para reportar el contenido de la lista.

Y por lo que he visto, un arrayList se llena así:

```
   Dim myAL As New ArrayList()
    myAL.Add("the")
    myAL.Add("quick")
    myAL.Add("brown")
    myAL.Add("fox")
    myAL.Add("jumps")
    myAL.Add("over")
    myAL.Add("the")
    myAL.Add("lazy")
    myAL.Add("dog")
    myAL.Add("in")
    myAL.Add("the")
    myAL.Add("barn")
```

Pero lo que yo busco es algo así como suele ser en Java

```
    miLista.Add(new Simbolo('Todos los parámetros'))
```

Es posible hacerlo con un ArrayListo o debo realizarlo de otra forma.

Agradezco su fina atención esperando su pronta ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El equivalente de `ArrayList` en .NET es la clase [`List(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Y la forma de crearla y agregarle elementos de tipo `Simbolo` según tu ejemplo es de esta manera:

```
Dim myAL As List(Of Simbolo) = New List(Of Simbolo)
myAL.Add(New Simbolo("Todos los parámetros"))
myAL.Add(New Simbolo("Todos los parámetros"))
```

o un poco simplificado:

```
Dim myAL = New List(Of Simbolo)
myAL.Add(New Simbolo("Todos los parámetros"))
myAL.Add(New Simbolo("Todos los parámetros"))
```

o, hasta un poco más simplificado usando [la sintaxis para inicializar colecciones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd293617.aspx):

```
Dim myAL = New List(Of Simbolo) From {
    New Simbolo("Todos los parámetros"),
    New Simbolo("Todos los parámetros")
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/DEMEDR60381)</kbd>

Comment: Disculpe, y para visualizar el contenido de la lista se debe hacer con un for-each. Lo estoy intentando pero me muestra en la salida NombreProyecto.Simbolo.

Comment: Me imagino que estás haciendo algo como `Console.WriteLine(simbolo)`. Si es el caso, toma en cuenta que funciona igual que Java, o sea, que si no redefinistes el `ToString` de la clase `Simbolo`, te va a presentar un resultado poco útil.

Answer (score 1):

Creas el `listOf`

```
Dim miArrayList = New List(Of Simbolo)
```

Ahora la cargas con los datos que quieras

```
Private numero As Integer

Private componente As String

Private lex As String

Private linea As Integer

Private columna As Integer
```

**Parametros**

```
miArrayList.Add(New Simbolo(numero,"componente","lex",linea,columna))
```

Al añadir esta linea de codigo, añades un objeto de tipo Simbolo a tu Lista creada.